# Clean code -- Java static functions and variable reuse

Tags: java, code-cleanup

I am trying to clean up a static function. Let me provide a template of this function here. It is a static function and is used only in two places in the code base one where the `isClient` is `true` and another where `isClient` is false.

```
public static void validate(BLangFunction resource, DiagnosticLog dlog, boolean resourceReturnsErrorOrNil,
                                boolean isClient) {
        if (!resourceReturnsErrorOrNil) {
            dlog.logDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, resource.pos, "Invalid return type: expected error?");
        }
        switch (resource.getName().getValue()) {
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_OPEN:
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_IDLE_TIMEOUT:
                validateOnOpenResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_TEXT:
                validateOnTextResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_BINARY:
                validateOnBinaryResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_PING:
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_PONG:
                validateOnPingPongResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_CLOSE:
                validateOnCloseResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            case WebSocketConstants.RESOURCE_NAME_ON_ERROR:
                validateOnErrorResource(resource, dlog, isClient);
                break;
            default:
                dlog.logDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, resource.pos,
                                   "Invalid resource name " + resource.getName().getValue() + " in service ");
        }

    }
```

The problem with this code is that the `dlog` variable is passed to all the other called functions as well as the `isClient` variable. And the `resourceReturnsErrorOrNil` is used in only one place.

I thought of refactoring the code to have non-static functions so that `dlog` can be a class variable and there could be two classes one for client and other for service with all the common code in a super class. Then I thought that this function is used only in two places and should we have instance classes for these?

The source code of this function can be found [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/c12b5c8842241a016f94ebd73a4a4fd187c016a9/stdlib/http/src/main/java/org/ballerinalang/net/http/compiler/WebSocketResourceValidator.java#L40).

What would be the best way to refactor based on the clean code principles?

Comment: why not keep it like it is? if you change it to class variables, you risk two threads to use it at the same time, and having the wrong value used

Comment: The problem as stated is that this is not very clean code. I would like to improve it. I don't think there will be a thread issue because I am not using multiple threads in this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I thought that this function is used only in two places and should we have instance classes for these?

That really depends on your goal. I agree, the current code is far from ideal. And the things you outlined all make sense. So, to answer your question: yes, if you think it will be helpful to the quality of your code base, having an "instance" class that only gets used in two places is perfectly fine.

The other thing to carefully look at: maybe there is a way to get rid of that switch. You could for example use a map (key: your constants, value: some Functional interface ... that makes the corresponding validation).

Comment: Can you please explain the second part of the explanation? How do I eliminate the switch using a map?

Comment: I think you meant this right? https://marcels-javanotes.blogspot.com/2016/09/replace-switch-statements-using-lamda.html

Comment: Actually I did refactor likewise and sent a PR :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The method should be made non static. This way, you can utilize dependency injection for the logging feature.